# Checkbox showing even if set to display none

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, plugins

I am using [Checkbox toggle plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Toggle-Button-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Checkbox.html) for a nice display of toggle effects in checkboxes.The concern is `Checkbox` is displaying along with the `togglebutton`.

**Jquery Checkbox display**

[image]

Interesting part is that on debuggin the html part ,I found  style of input checkbox is set to `display:none`.

**Jquery plugin calling**

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Gender, new {@class="chkbxSwitch", @id = "chkbxGender" })
 $("#chkbxGender").checkboxpicker({
    offClass: 'btn-primary',
    onClass: 'btn-primary',
    offLabel:'MALE',   
    onLabel: 'FEMALE'

});
```

**Rendered HTML Output**

```
<input class="chkbxSwitch" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Gender field is required." 
id="chkbxGender" name="Gender" type="checkbox" value="true" style="display: none;">
         <div class="btn-group" tabindex="0">
             <a class="btn active btn-primary">MALE</a>
             <a class="btn btn-default">FEMALE</a>
         </div>
         <input name="Gender" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above scenario by defining css mentioned as below

```
    #chkbxGender
    {
        display:none !important
    }
```